# Symfony3 security.token_storage returns different entity data than Symfony2

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

I have upgraded a Symfony 2.3 application to Symfony 3.0.4, after a lot of messing around I was able to get almost every issue resolved. The issue that I am now having is that when I am getting the `User` entity from the `security.token_storage` in Symfony3 it is returning a user without some of the data it has when getting the user entity from the `security.context` in Symfony2.

Symfony2:

```
$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

returns a user entity with the customers in it:

```
customers: {array}[1]
```

Symfony3:

```
$user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
```

returns a user entity with no customers in it:

```
customers: null
```

I am looking for any help on why it would not be functioning the same or what I should look at to see the difference.

We are using Doctrine ORM for the initial getting of the user entity. Is it possible that I could have missed something with the way caching is done in the latest version of Doctrine?

Comment: more probably you upgrade doctrine2 also and the problem chould be in the mapping. Can you post the entity's relation definition?

Answer (score 0):

[Security.token_storage](http://'security.token_storage') works fine in your example.

You should check code in the [token and/or user provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html).

If you are using doctrine2, then probably you need [eager loading](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-eager-loading) in your entity ?

I have no knowledge about doctrine1 :(

Comment: LOL who is masochistic enough to still use `Doctrine 1`... Kinda curious, is `Doctrine 1` still well spread? :)

Comment: Ok so i looked at your suggestion and it turns out in our custom user provider i had removed one of the interfaces so it looked like this  "class UserProvider extends EntityRepository implements UserLoaderInterface" and once i added the userproviderinterface to it things worked as they should. "class UserProvider extends EntityRepository implements UserLoaderInterface, UserProviderInterface".